# Where is the StackBlitz console?

Tags: angular, console, stackblitz

At the end of the Angular's "Getting started/try it/using forms for user inputs", we are asked at the end to "open the console to see an object containing the name and address you submitted.". But I only have a terminal where the app is running, and a classic terminal at my disposal.

Where is the console which shows the log of (in cart.component.ts line 28):

```js
console.warn('Your order has been submitted', this.checkoutForm.value);
```

[image]

It's not in the inspect page.

[Edit]

To me it's not at the bottom of the page as Robert proposed. Maybe there's a console option to enable somewhere?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the "ready-made sample project in StackBlitz" from Angular "try it/Getting started", it doesn't have a console.

The console is present as Roberts screen shows when you create a new project from StackBlitz.

Answer (score 4):

I experienced the same thing, where the forked "Getting Started" Angular project on StackBlitz didn't show a console option. To see a console I clicked "open in new tab" in the top right, and then I used the browser console (e.g. to see Chrome's console right click on the output page and select 'Inspect', then click on the 'Console' tab).

[View open in new tab button location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmkJA.jpg) 
[image]

View example chrome console;
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It should be at the bottom of the page:

[image]

**Update**
If you happend to use Vite etc. WebContainers then open the DevTools (F12):

[image]

Comment: Ignore downvote, which browser you use? have you tried to reload the whole page? try to start a brand new project is it there?

Comment: How did you get the terminal?

Comment: @EugenSunic press F12

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you could use `alert`:

`alert(this.checkoutForm.value.address);`

The `alert` method displays a popup box with whatever message you pass it. More info [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_alert.asp)